# How do you specify log locations for machine converge actions in chef?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-provisioning

Given a chef machine resource like the following:

```
machine "my-server" do
  action :converge_only
end
```

When this converge happens we sometimes get a chef status of `Aborted` on [manage.chef.io](http://manage.chef.io) with no further information.  This makes it very difficult to troubleshoot issues with the recipes.

I have the following questions:

- Where is the log on the remote machine?
- Can I specify the local log location for the converge?
- Is there a way to rotate the log? It would be useful to be able to go back to previous chef runs and see the logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer my own question, you specify logging in the client.rb.  You can append settings to the client.rb via the `chef_config` property in the machine resource.  Here's a small example:

```
machine "my-server" do
  action :setup
  chef_config "\r\nlog_level :debug\r\nlog_location \"C:\\\\chef\\\\chef-client.#{Time.now.to_i}.log\"\r\n\r\nverbose_logging true"
end
```

I'm not sure if specifying this on the `:converge` will do anything.  It definitely works on the `:setup`.